# Python: Strange output when calculate md5

Tags: python, md5

When i calculate MD5 for a file in Python i get a strange output.
My function :

```
def md5_for_file(self, fname, block_size=2**20):
    f = open(fname)
    data = f.read()
    m = md5.new()
    if len(data)>0:
        m.update(data)
        f.close()
        return m.digest()
```

Output :

[output http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/6615/20j7.png](http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/6615/20j7.png)

I need to convert that to utf8 or what?!

Comment: `md5` is deprecated. You should use `hashlib` instead. http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`digest` is returning the digest as a binary string representing the array of bytes. If you want your digest in hex, e.g. to display it to the user, use the `hexdigest` method instead.

Also, [as pointed out by Cfreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804820/python-strange-output-when-calculate-md5/18804837#comment27732946_18804820), `md5` is deprecated, you should use [`hashlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib) instead. Finally, your function is not using the `block_size` parameter - it will always read the whole file into memory in order to calculate the digest.

Comment: Thank you! hexdigest works! Yeah...i forgot about the block_size and i'm forced to use python 2.2 so i can't use hashlib and also i couldn't find hashlib for windows and so on... Thank you again! :D

Comment: Hmm... Why python MD5 is different than php/visual basic MD5 of the same file?

Comment: @Cataclismo Maybe you forgot to open the file in binary mode? Either way, this seems like material for a new question - with more information and reproducible examples, of course...